# Converting LAB value from D65 to D50

Tags: color-conversion

I'm building a database for the anime cel color(acrylic paint). I scanned them with an Epson Perfection v600 scanner calibrated with Silverfast's advance target, saving in TIFF with ProPhoto RGB profile embedded, since many of the color are out of gamut for sRGB and AdobeRGB.

There's a database I found online that someone had already built many years ago. His data were measured by a Noritsu CS-CM1000 colorimeter using D65 luminance. I want to see if our measurement matches, so I took a common color we have and compare their LAB values. However his color was measured in D65 and mine was in D50 (from my scanner). So how do I convert his number to D50?

The color I picked for comparison is a bright pink. From my scanner it is `LAB(84, 39, 6)`. On his chart it is `LAB(83, 17, 10)`.

Comment: @user287001 the color were labeled by code. I picked the one I have that I know its code  and compare it to the one in his database.

Comment: (continued) how do you know that your piece has not changed its color during the times? Is it a brand new one and the manufactured has guaranteed that the colors are the same as they were in pieces which were new years ago?

Comment: @user287001 they are acrylic paint, they don't change color if kept in good condition for years. I have multiple cels of the same character brought from different sellers, and their color all matches. If the paint were to deteriorate through the years, they would have deteriorate in different stages from different sellers and wouldn't look the same.

Comment: OK. D50 and D65 are different power density distributions over the visible wavelength range. Lab numbers which are measured under certain illuminant do not carry exact information of what would be the measurement result under another illuminant. That's because one cannot calculate from 3 numbers what's the reflection spectrum of the material. 3 numbers is a poor image of reflection spectrum over visible wavelength range. The conversion you expect can be based on assumptions. See this. http://www2.cmp.uea.ac.uk/Research/compvis/Papers/FinSuss_COL00.pdf  It's too dense for me.

Comment: (continued) And this one: hrcak.srce.hr/file/95370 It's as dense. Both of them are academic works which contain "how to calculate the color under a different illuminant"  This site  http://www.brucelindbloom.com has some practical calculators and chromatic adaptation matrices ready to use. But chromatic adaptation matrices are based on heavy assumptions of the behaviour of the color materials.

Comment: @user287001 I tried that calculator but I don't know how to use it. I set the ref white to D65 -> enter the lab value -> click `Lab` button. Then what do I do?

Comment: Illuminant should not be changed in the CIE color calculator. Illuminant should be the one which was the white when the Lab numbers were measured. The CIE color calculator cannot have a slightest idea how the material might look in other white. There's the chromatic adaptation part. Try the version "From D50 to D65".  Read the whole story which tells what the matrices do. Math can be tricky.

Comment: You should convert a D50 Lab color to XYZ,. Then calculate new XYZ values with Bradford's chromatic adaptation guess  under D65 and finally convert the result to Lab D65. Note that there's used assumption "linear transformation works" .

Comment: @user287001 I just found this calculator from [nixsensor](https://www.nixsensor.com/free-color-converter/) that can do the conversion. In the result, the converted D50 Lab value wasn't that much apart from the D65 source. So the fact our measures are so different probably means his measurement device was faulty.

Comment: Or his sample was colored differently. Or your scanner based method is still inaccurate.Does your current method output right numbers from a color book sheet and are the scanned numbers same for an acrylic sample and same looking color book sheet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132619/discussion-between-reddy-and-user287001).